# Isomorphism of $S[t^2]$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, graded-rings

I get lost reading a passage.

> Let $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a standard graded polynomial ring and let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal of $S$. I would like to understand why there is an isomorphism $$S[It,t^2]\cong S[t^2]\oplus\Big(S[t^2]\otimes_S It\Big)$$
>   as $S[t^2]$-modules, where $t$ is a new variable and $\deg(t)=1$.

I'm not even sure of why $S[t^2]\otimes_S It$ is an $S[t^2]$-module. Given $$f\in S[t^2]\quad\text{ and}\quad\sum g_i\otimes h_i\in S[t^2]\otimes_S It,$$ is it right to define
$$f\cdot\left(\sum g_i\otimes h_i\right):=\sum(fg_i)\otimes h_i\ ?$$
And if this is OK, could anyone give me a hint for the isomorphism above? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Your description of the $S[t^2]$-module structure on $S[t^2]\otimes_S It$ is correct.  More generally, is $B$ is an $A$-algebra and $M$ is an $A$-module, $B\otimes_A M$ is a $B$-module in the same way.

As a hint for the isomorphism, $S[It,t^2]$ is just those polynomials whose odd-degree coefficients are all in $I$.  This is the direct sum of two submodules: one consisting of polynomials with only even-degree terms, and one consisting of polynomials with only odd-degree terms.  Identify these submodules with the summands of $S[t^2]\oplus S[t^2]\otimes_S It$.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, it is a general fact that if you have an R-algebra S (that is, a ring homomorphism R -> S), and an R-module M, then $S \otimes_R M$ is an $S$ module defined in a natural way $s \cdot (s' \otimes m) = (ss') \otimes m$.

Comment: Geometrically, if you view M as a "fiber bundle" (actually quasicoherent sheaf) over R (actually over the scheme Spec R), it is a pullback of that bundle corresponding to the map Spec S -> Spec R (Spec is a contravariant functor).